# Java indentation and alignment issue

Tags: java, indentation

[image: unaligned indentation]

Hi guys, so I made this program where I face some indentation problem at Game Outcome: section. The issue I have is that if both player say Y to draw a card or N to draw a card, the indentation will be aligned. but if one say Y and the other say N, the alignment will be slightly off. I went counting the space and both were indented correctly. That's when I realize that after "]", the "space" became shorter, which is the cause of alignment going off. When I try to save the outcome and open with notepad, the indentation is correct as well. (which means code should have nothing wrong I hope.) 
How would I solve the issue of incorrect alignment in this case? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There could be several explanations for this.  From what you described, it sounds like your font is not a true mono-spaced font.  In other words, things should be lining up from a character count, but are not.  Maybe you could change the output destination to something like a prompt or the bash.

Comment: Sorry sir to trouble you, if my program doesn't allow me to change font, would it be possible to implement some codes or sort that can change the font output?

Comment: This isn't really a Java problem.  Just send your output to a text file and then open it using a true monospaced editor like Notepad.

Comment: The suit symbols are wider than the other characters, as you can see in the image. That means that this font is un*suit*able.